# What is the value of $<\psi _m|\psi _n>$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, fourier-transform, normalization

I am currently studying quantum mechanics at University, and it was my understanding that $ <\psi _m|\psi _n> = \delta_{mn}$ integrated over all space available to the particle. 1 when $m =n$ and $0$ otherwise.

However I recently came across this integral where the Fourier series is used to solve it   $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i(k_m - k_n)x} dx = 2\pi \delta_{mn}$$

I don't understand why the bottom integral is multiplied by $2\pi$? 
My only guess is that it is because the wavefunctions I have dealt with in QM have always been normalised

Comment: Yes, it is because of normalisation. The plane wave (which you are integrating in the second equation) is normalised with a factor $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$

Comment: What is the question? It seems the asker figured out the answer himself. lol.

Comment: @tomph thanks. I thought this would be it but I wasn't sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first equation is the orthonormality condition for the two states (so you are requiring they are normalized). The second equation describes one integral form of the delta function.
In order to have a relation between these two equations, you have to consider that $| \psi_n>= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{i k_n x}$  in your first equation. The wave functions are indeed normalized.